# how to make a admin password in HTML + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
</script>
<button onclick="password1()">Password</button>
<script>
    function password1(){
     var pass = prompt ("Password"); -- Pasword Prompt
     var wo = "No";                  -- If Wrong
     var rd = "Yes";                 -- If Correct
     var awn = 123;                  -- Code
     if (pass == 123) {              -- Check the password
     document.write(rd);

     }
    }
</script>
```

> This is what i tried but for a reason nothing appears Please help me

Comment: Could you please tell us what you want to achieve?

Comment: It works well the only problems in the code are your comments -- Password Prompt -- If Wrong

Comment: It should write "Yes" in case you enter `123` in the prompt, right @Ivan?

Answer (score 0):

- Wrong comments
- No "else" statement
- Variable "awn" defined but never used

```js
<script>
    function password1(){
        var pass = prompt("Password");  // Pasword Prompt
        var wo = "No";                  // If Wrong
        var rd = "Yes";                 // If Correct
        var awn = 123;                  // Code
        if (pass == awn) {              // Check the password
            document.write(rd);
        } else {
            document.write(wo)
        }
    }
</script>
```